# how to document encryption and signing requirements for xml batch files?

Tags: xml, security, soa, ws-security

I have an xml batch file that will be transferred between two parties over scp/sftp (no webservices involved). Parts of the xml batch files I am sending need to be encrypted and signed.

I need to document the encryption/signing requirements so that third parties can understand how to work with the batch files.  I may just create an interface specification document (e.g. in MS word) that describes the encryption and signing requirements.  However, I was wondering if WS-Policy could also be used for documenting the security requirements for xml messages that aren't part of web services?

Would it make sense to create a wsdl for this service, even though web services aren't being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a nice idea :) of course you can use WS-SecurityPolicy to describe it and keep it formal :) if you want you could write a pice of verifier that will understand ws-securityPolicy outside the WS scope.